# Android: Which is better, develop Android app on a mac or a windows pc?

Tags: android

What is better, to develop my Android app on a Windows PC or a mac?

Comment: my friend whom are a mac fanboy thinks mac. I who prefer windows, think windows. Use the OS you are most comfortable with, there are no significant difference to my knowledge.

Comment: I thank you for that comment and welcome more!

Comment: Not much of a difference, if your going to use the NDK extensively then a Linux based environment may be better suited, but otherwise it would be just personal preference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to Apple's (to put it politely) "controlling" approach to development, you'll need a Mac to develop apps for the iPhone. So, if you think it's likely you'll be porting any of your Android apps accross to the iPhone in the near future, you might as well save yourself buying two lots of dev hardware and start with a Mac.

Also, emulating a Mac OS on a PC is hard work and against Apples ToS, but you can run a Windows OS natively on a Mac.

Comment: You can run Windows on a Mac, fully supported by Apple - no emulation in sight.  You could also purchase something like VMware Fusion or Parallels Desktop to run Linux on said Mac.

Comment: There are some unofficial ways of running Mac OS on a PC, see www.hackintosh.com

Comment: @tomlog True enough, it is *technically* possible, but the amount of time (which = money) to get an out-of-date, severely hobbled version of a Mac OS working is just not worth it if you are a serious developer. Also, it's not just unofficial, it's downright illegal to emulate a Mac OS on a PC.

Comment: Great! This is why I originally asked the question - I've developed my app on Windows and now I'll be developing it for the iphone and I thought maybe that having everything in one place (on one machine) would be less confusing and more organized. I plan on getting a mac-mini to start with. It'll hook up to a regular windows monitor and any other usb peripherals. (under $600 new too!) Great answer MatW - (you too tomlog and Andy).

Answer (score 6):

Because the API docs are not always complete, having [access to the Android source code](http://source.android.com/download) can be of great benefit. Unfortunately, setting this up for Windows is not currently supported by Android, but is for Linux or Mac OS. You can do it for Windows, but there is no procedure explained to do so, and it's not intuitive.

So in the case of easily being able to download and view the source, either Linux or Mac would be a better option than Windows.

Comment: Surely you could *view* the source on any system with a text editor? Compile and run it may be different, but view?

Comment: @Dan: getting the source is not that simple. If you have a script that lists what to pull it can be done. For Mac OS and Linux, Google provides a utility and setup instructions. Not so for Windows, you're left on your own.

Comment: Fair enough, I stand corrected - never realised they made it so difficult.

Comment: Thanks JRL and Dan, I appreciates ya.

Answer (score 6):

I've developed Android on OS X, Ubuntu Linux and Windows XP, and in my experience it makes very little difference. It's also easy to chop-and-change. Pick the OS you prefer.

Comment: Hey, thanks Jim. But...wouldn't it be better to have all files, ideas, docs, etc. on a mac if a person knows that their going to develop for both Android and iphone? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Subjective question. It all depends on personal preference. Do you like Windows and Linux? Use PC. Do you like MacOS? Then you know the answer :). Java is the main language for Android development and Google actively supports all popular OS. So, the development tools for different platforms exist in sufficient quantity.

Comment: Thanks Anry, you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll be using the eclipse IDE it will make little if any difference what OS you choose. Eclipse can run on a MAC Windows or Linux.

Comment: Thanks Zerayaqob - I sure do like Eclipse...I've often wondered what language Eclipse was programmed under?